# Type Script. The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type

Tags: typescript

Делаю шахматы, пока только разбираюсь с TS и перерыв сайты,  решения не нашла. Добавление к переменным Number не помогает.
Проблема в условии, пишет об ошибке:

> **"The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type."**

Конкретно на строку: `if ((i+j)& 2 !== 0) {`

Весь код файла:

```
import { Cell } from "./Cell";
import { Color } from "./Color";

export class Board {
    cells: Cell[][] = []

    public initCells() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            const row: Cell[] = []
            for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                if ((i+j)& 2 !== 0) {
                    row.push (new Cell (this, j, i, Color.BLACK, null))
                }
                else {
                    row.push(new Cell(this, j, i, Color.WHITE, null))
                }
            }
            this.cells.push(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите тип Cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У оператора `&` приоритет ниже чем у `!==`. Так что ваше условие TS (и JS) понимает как `(i + j) & (2 !== 0)` и ругается потому что тип выражения `(2 !== 0)` будет `boolean`, а оператор `&` ожидает число.

Либо поставьте скобки `if (((i + j) & 2) !== 0) ...`, либо вообще уберите сравнение `if ((i + j) & 2)) ...`, оно тут не несёт большого смысла.

Либо вообще не используйте `&` который тут только запутывает, а используйте остаток от деления `if ((i + j) % 2 === 0)`.